# Dix mille Anglais sont tombés dans la Tamise

Tags: proverbes, jeux

I cannot find what the part in Italics refers to.
Please help.  Thanks in advance.  --- tk

> Était-il pensable qu’on entende toujours *Dix mille Anglais sont tombés dans la Tamise pour ne pas avoir joué atout*. (*Les Années*, Annie Ernaux, pages 97)

Comment: It's a reference to the bridge card game, we have a saying in French (I don't know if they have it in English) « *Cent mille Anglais se sont jetés dans la Tamise pour ne pas avoir joué atout*. ».  By the way, another typo in your copy of the book: Di**x**.  *Jouer atout* → play trump.

Comment: Thanks, None, for the answer.

Comment: It is not the typo in my copy.  It was my error in typing, the PDF file being the kind from which I cannot copy and paste.  --- tk

Comment: He talk about a card game called ""Belote coinché" in french.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a French Language question but a Games/Cards question. Plus, the first result when you google the literal sentence explains exactly what the expression means in Bridge.

Comment: @tk Did you research before asking and what were the results? From the FLSE Help Center: *Search, and research // Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?* https://french.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 4):

This is a reference to the bridge card game. There's a saying in French that goes: *Cent mille Anglais se sont jetés dans la Tamise pour ne pas avoir joué atout*.
*Jouer atout* : to play (a) trump.

There can be variants on the number, (sometimes *dix mille*, sometimes *two million*, etc...), and it can also be used metaphorically to express that someone highly regrets not having done the right choice, but here Annie Ernaux is describing a bridge card game, so she hears it as people are playing bridge.

An English translation of Annie Ernaux's book we can [find on the web](https://readfrom.net/annie-ernaux/page,7,162211-the_years.html) is : "Coffee was served, the table cleared, and a game of bridge set up. [...] How was it possible that people still said Ten thousand English jumped into the Thames for not having trumped."

I don't think the same saying is used in English. In the English translation of Agatha Christie's *N or M?*: " “When in doubt lead a Trump, they say,” she twittered, and laid down the Nine of Diamonds." is translated into French as *Elle eu recours à la plaisanterie habituelle : des milliers d'anglais se sont jetés dans la Tamise pour n'avoir pas joué atout... Elle posa sur la table son neuf de carreaux.*

Comment: Beaucoup plus clair avec "se sont jeté" plutôt que "sont tombés".